# Password stored in MobileSafari memory

Tags: html, ios, autocomplete, mobile-safari, heap-memory

I have a simple login form on my website, using .Net MVC. When the form is submitted a partial view is loaded with a success message. A simplified version of the form can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/hev4f64f/10/

**The Problem:**
When the above form is loaded in MobileSafari (jsfiddle.net/hev4f64f/10/show/) using simulator or iPad and submitted, on inspecting the process memory dump I see the password in memory in plain t text.
I am using the method described [here](https://filippo.io/dumping-the-ios-simulator-memory/) for inspecting MobileSafari memory dump, and then searching for the password using the following command:

```
grep -a 'P@$$W0Rd' core.1234
```

Following is a sample occurrence of the password "southpark" in the dump.

> NS.boolval$clasNSNumber
>                          NS.object.3     NS.bytes southpark$clasNSStrinNS.key.9 
>   NS.byte'ControlLooksLikePasswordCredentialField$clasNSString  NS.key.11
>   NS.byte)ControlLooksLikeCreditCardCardholderField$clasNSString
>                                                    NS.object.21 $classNSNull    NS.key.12
>   NS.byteControlIsDisabled$clasNSString

Not sure what "ControlLooksLikePasswordCredentialField" in the dump means. 
My initial guess was it has something to do with the Safari Password Manager, but I have set autocomplete=off in the form. I am also clearing the fields in the client after form submission.

Any idea how to get rid of the password in memory?

Comment: For anyone else who comes across the same issue, I implemented a workaround solution using http://plugins.jquery.com/disable-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across the same issue, I implemented a workaround solution using plugins.jquery.com/disable-autocomplete